# ObservableCollection created on a Thread Pool Thread does not filter

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionviewsource

The application I am working on is is based on WPF and the MVVMLightToolkit. I know I am not providing you a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but the whole application is really complex and it is hard to provide such an example. I hope someone will be able to help with the whole picture.

In that application, one action takes a lot of time (initialization stuff), so I run it in a task to not freeze the UI:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICommand HeavyActionCommand {get; private set;}
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.HeavyActionCommand = new RelayCommand(this.HeavyAction);
    }
    private async void HeavyAction()
    {
        var subViewModel = new SubViewModel();
        await Task.Run(async () => await subViewModel.ActualHeavyAction());
    }
}
```

If I do not wrap the `ActualHeavyAction` in the `Task.Run` method, the UI freeze. Doing this, as far as I understand, the `ActualHeavyAction` is not ran on the UI thread but on a Thread Pool Thread (correct me if I am wrong).

Among other things `ActualHeavyAction` initializes an `ObservableCollection` that I need to filter regarding to some user live inputs (in the following class, the property `UserInput` is bound to a `TextBox`). I had something like:

```
public class SubViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private _userInput;
    public string UserInput
    {
        get { return _userInput; }
        set
        {
            if (_userInput != value)
            {
                _userInput = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();

                // Run the filter on the collection when the user enters new inputs
                CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.MyCollection).Refresh();
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection MyCollection {get; private set;}

    public async Task ActualHeavyAction()
    {
        /// lots of heavy stuff

        var myCollection = await _context.Objects.GetCollectionAsync();
        this.MyCollection = new ObservableCollection(myCollection);

        this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.MyCollection));

        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.MyCollection).Filter = MyFilter;

        /// some other heavy stuff
    }

    public bool MyFilter(object obj)
    {
        // Blah blah blah
    }
}
```

Until here, I do not have any trouble. The problem occures later, when another action, ran on the UI Thread modify that collection. I get the recurrent:

> This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread

To fix it, I try to add the .NET 4.5 `EnableCollectionSynchronization` feature:

```
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this.MyCollection, lockObject); // lockObject is a static new object() defined in the SubViewModel class
```

I try to add it right after and just before the call to: `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView`

Doing so, I do not get the exception when I modify `MyCollection`, but calling `Refresh()` on the `CollectionView` does not run the `MyFilter` method (the exact same code work on other ViewModels that are not initialized on a Thread Pool Thread).

Do you have any idea of what's wrong with my code?

Comment: WPF really hates threads and doesn't always yell at you when you get it wrong.  Keep UI initialization on the main thread, use a splash screen to cover it up.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah, I can see that. My problem is it is not the UI init but just a screen init. I put a Progress Bar during the execution of the task instead. But as I said, it freezes if I do not put the Task stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` method should be called on the UI thread. So you need to create the `ObservableCollection` and call this method on the UI thread *before* you try to access the collection from the background thread.

But the only method that should be called on a background thread in your `ActualHeavyAction()` is the `GetCollectionAsync()` method.

Once the task that calls this method completes, you could create the `ObservableCollection` and apply the filter back on the UI thread. Or just returned an already filtered list from the task.

Filtering an `ICollectionView` using the `Filter` property is a flexible but quite slow operation so if your source collection contains a lot of items, this might not be the best option to implement filtering.

Comment: Actually, `GetCollectionAsync()` is not that long. It is others calls replaced by my comment that take a lots of time. However, I can try to put only those calls into a background thread (instead of the whole HeavyActionMethod). Once awaited, the execution of the rest of the methods will be on the UI thread right ?

Comment: Then the filterting is apparently to slow. Read my last sentence again.

Comment: The freezing is not due to the filtering but all the other stuff done before and after.

Comment: And what exactly is that? Is it something that you can do on a background thread? Then, do it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant in my first comments. I will try it as soon as I have the time. For now, I just removed the `Task.Run` and the application freezes, but the filtering works.